# In app subscription minimum rate

Tags: android

Is there any minimum subscription rate for android in app subscriptions. I was trying to look into that but inapp billing shows as .99$ but if i avail for a weekly subscription, I want that little less.Is there any possibility to do that,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the country in which the user is located. Germany for example allows a minimum price of 0.5€ which is around 0.525$.

You can see the full list of the price ranges on the [Developer Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286)